# rvm env mistake leads to continuous "Unrecognized command line flag" error message

Tags: rvm

Earlier today, when trying to fix an issue, I ran this command.

rvm env --path--

Which apparently set my env variable to path.

Pretty much every single rvm command now prints out

Unrecognized command line argument --path--

How do I correct this?

I'd like to revert to /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby, or undo this change.

It was a lot of work to get rvm and openssl and PostGres to work together on this Ubuntu machine, so I'd prefer a one or two-line fix to reinstalling everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: `unset rvm_error; rvm-restart`, also make sure to report this bug to RVM => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: Thank you immensely. This solved my problem in 5 seconds. I'll report this bug to RVM.